# Avoiding automatic creation of JMS queue in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-artemis

I want to change the default behaviour of Apache Camel so that if the JMS queue `myQueue` is already present then the date from the CSV file will be sent to the queue, and if queue `myQueue` is not present already then instead of automatically creating it I want to throw some error/exception indicating that queue is not present there already.
Anyone having any idea/know how to change the configuration?

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis and this Java route for sending data from CSV file to target queue:

```java
from("file:C:/inputFolder?fileName=EventData.csv").split(body().tokenize("\n"
 )).log("${body}") // .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut) // //
  .to("jms:queue:myQueue");
```

Comment: Whether or not the queue is automatically created depends on how the JMS _broker_ is configured. Camel can't do anything about that as it's just using the JMS API. So, what broker are you using?

Comment: spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616                                                                     Broker url I am using inside the application.properties file. So what needs to done now to acheive the goal.

Comment: That URL could be used to connect to ActiveMQ "Classic" or ActiveMQ Artemis. Which one are you using? The configuration for each is different.

Comment: Not sure but what will be the configration for activemq "Classic"

Comment: See https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-restrict-connections-from-creating-new-queues-or-topics.

Comment: Sorry, I was using Activemq Artemis,By default Apache ActiveMQ Artemis will automatically create addresses and queues to support the semantics of whatever protocol you're using.no manual configuration is required .so what will be the configuration for activemq artemis

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following address settings in `broker.xml`:

- `<auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>`
- `<auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>`

For example:

```xml
      <address-settings>
         <address-setting match="#">
            <auto-create-queues>false</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>false</auto-create-addresses>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>
```